# Need help writing an IF Statement in Exel

Tags: if-statement

I really need someone's help what I am try to write is:
`If E10=High then return 0.337 or if E10=Medium then return 0.086 or if E10=Low then return 0.017`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of If Function in Excel is as follows:

```
=IF(Logic_Test, Value_if_True, Value_if_False)
```

your logic test: `e10="High"`
your value if true: `0.337`

your value if false is the rest of your expression: `if E10=Medium then return 0.086 or if E10=Low then return 0.017`.  Repeat the process:

logic test: `e10="Medium"`
value if true: `0.086`
value if false... `if E10=Low then return 0.017`  Let's assume that `Low` is the only other option, then we can combine the values:

```
=IF(e10="High", 0.337, IF(e10="Medium", 0.086, 0.017))
```

This might be better done with a lookup table (and the hlookup/vlookup functions), but that is more advanced...

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome. Upvote all answers that were useful (up arrow next to the answer), and select the answer that solved your problem (check mark in the same area).  This lets future users know what worked (and it gives me points :-)

Answer (score 0):

Nest your if statements. The `if true` value can be another expression. Look at the ([documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)), it's in the examples under "Nested If examples"